# header is ~60% wider than parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The header on my new site is about 60% wider than the body and is x-scrollable. There shouldn't be any overflow at all. I placed a border around the ul to check it, but that wasn't the problem. Is there a conflict between my JS and CSS?

```css
    html {
 width: 100%;
}

* {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *::after, *::before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }



.header {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #222323;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 
 -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
 transform-origin: center top;
}

.logo img {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 9%;
 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
 transform-origin: center top; 
}


ul {
 z-index: 101;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 top: 60px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 
}
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
   
  var intro = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  var head = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
  var logo = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
  var tl = new TimelineLite();
  
   tl.to(intro, 2, {opacity: 0.5, delay:1})
   tl.to(intro, 1, {opacity: 1}, 2)
   tl.to(head, 1, {scaleY: 0.2}, 3)
   tl.to(logo, 1, {scaleX:0.2}, 3)
   tl.to(nav, 2, {opacity: 1}, 4.5);
  }
 </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="init()">
 <div class="header" id="head">
  <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/logo-white.png"></a>
 </div>  
 <ul id="navbar">
  <div class="left">
   <li><a href="index.html" id="home" class="hoverbox">home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html" id="about" class="hoverbox">about</a></li>
   <li><a href="services.html" id="services" class="hoverbox">services</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="right"> 
   <li><a href="work.html" id="work" class="hoverbox">work</a></li>
   <li><a href="process.html" id="process" class="hoverbox">process</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html" id="contact" class="hoverbox">contact</a></li>
  </div> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: The CSS would seem to merely set the ```.header``` element to 100% of the viewport. But there's a lot going on here with the JavaScript especially with the use of a 3rd party library. Can you supply a CodePen or JSFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the response. I don't know how to embed the codepen on here, but here's the link. Don't worry too much about the placement of everything. Just the scrolling nav. 
http://codepen.io/BadAnderson/pen/LVMrPe/

Answer (score 1):

The scrolling nav is caused by `div.right`. In your `.right` class you have `left: 840px;` and this pushes the element to the right out of the viewport, therefore causing the scroll. A quick solution would be to set `position: absolute` and `right: 0`:

```
.right {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 840px;
  right: 0;
}
```

But I would seriously consider reviewing all the code (css and html), because there seems to be a lot of things used out of place.